# how to access variables from one ajax function to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, controller

This is view file script code function

```
function getState(val) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ URL::to('admin/state_change') }}" + "/" + val, //url route 
    controller in route.php
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      var lid = data.lawid;             //getting value from controller
      var scn = data.sortname;          //getting value from controller
      var finlawid = 'L'+scn+'C'+lid;   //concatinating
      $("#lm_id").val(finlawid);        // Lm_id is textbox id
    }
  });
}
```

I want to access the lid an scn variable in below function which present in same file

```
function getStatename(val) {
  if (val >= 0) {
    // access lid and scn to concatinat more characters and assigned it to lm_id textbox
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `getStatename`?

Comment: In dropdownlist onChange="getStatename()" properties  and value is assigned to each option. @Philipp

Comment: how to access is main important i dont knw how to do that

Comment: Keep the variables in the global scope outside the function. You can then use them in both the functions. `    var lid, scn, finlawid;
    function getState(val)
    {
        lid = 1;
    }

    function getStatename(val)
    {
        console.log(lid);
    }`

Comment: but lid is taking value from database so can i take the another variable name

Comment: Why dont you just do what you have to do in the ajax success part?